# AWS Lambda not getting invoked when binary data posted in AWS IOT?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-iot

I have configured a lambda to a IOT Rule. The MQTT topic will get binary data and on arrival of data the rule should invoke lambda.

The lambda gets invoked when I post normal JSON data, but if I post any binary data, the lambda does not get invoked.

But at the same time, I am able to consume the binary data posted to MQTT through my stand alone consumer and able to deserialise it successfully.

So what is that I am missing here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the message payload should be handled as raw binary data (rather than a JSON object), you can use the * operator to refer to it in a SELECT clause.

Do this on your rule:

SELECT encode(*, 'base64') AS data, timestamp() AS ts FROM 'a/b'

This way it will get invoked.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-sql-select.html

Comment: I was previously using SELECT * from 'a/b', looks like even this query should have invoked the lambda as per documentation. I will give a try with the rule suggested by you.

Comment: As a follow-up for anyone who can't this working, the following
`SELECT  timestamp() AS ts, encode(*, 'base64') AS data FROM 'a/b'` - does not work but..
`SELECT encode(*, 'base64') AS data, timestamp() AS ts FROM 'a/b'` - does.

The base64 statement must come first.

Comment: My data is already base64 encoded, this causes it to be double encoded.  If it possible to receive raw base64 days without double encoding?

Comment: I am also trying the same thing. AWS lambda function should invoke when AWS IoT receives payload in binary. How does ```SELECT encode(*, 'base64') AS data, timestamp() AS ts FROM 'a/b'``` query trigger lambda function without calling AWS IoT core SQL ```aws_lambda``` function?